# URL quote PostgreSQL database password in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using Django 1.9.2 and psyopg2 2.6.1 with Python 3.5.0 in a project that I created with http://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. I have a database configuration that looks like this:

```
import environ
from django.utils.http import urlquote
env = environ.Env()

DATABASES = {
    # 1) This does not work.
    # 'default': env.db("DATABASE_URL",
    #                   default="postgres://myuser:%s@127.0.0.1:5432/mydb" % "1234#abc")
    # 2) This does not work.
    # 'default': env.db("DATABASE_URL",
    #                   default="postgres://myuser:%s@127.0.0.1:5432/mydb" % urlquote("1234#abc"))

    # 3) This works 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': '1234#abc',
        'PORT': 5432,
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1'
    }
}
```

My database password has a `#` in it. I can successfully connect with option #3 option, but with the other two I receive these errors:

1) `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1234'`

2) `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myuser"`.

How do I properly send this password with a `#` to PostgreSQL?

Comment: `urlquote('1234#abc')` will return `1234%23abc` which clearly doesn't match your database's password.

Comment: @xyres I've updated the question to make my issue clearer.

Comment: [It's a bug](http://github.com/joke2k/django-environ/issues/55). The author of the django-environ library has made a [pull request](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ/pull/69) to fix this bug but still hasn't merged it.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding it as a raw string, ie, in your case:

```
 'default': env.db("DATABASE_URL",
    default="postgres://myuser:%s@127.0.0.1:5432/mydb" % r"1234#abc")
```

Post back with your results.